# Use PDF on python code

Tags: python, pdf

I'm working with python and I have a pdf file. I tried to find an html but I wasn't able to do that. In the pdf I have a table and I need the data inside it. I try to change it in html (that I'm able to work with) and text but I have only a list of strange symbols. Can you help me? My specific question is: Is there the possibility to extract a PDF file with python? I want to extract the text and then working on it (checking the words or the time. It is a bus schedule)

```
filename = "bus.pdf"
import slate
with open('example.pdf') as f:
    doc = slate.PDF(f)
    print(doc)
```

Comment: Have you heard of slate? If not just check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate

Comment: Yes I tried to do that but python return "NameError: name 'slate' is not defined". Is there some import to do?

Comment: You have to download the slate package and then import slate

Comment: Ok. Where can I download it?

Comment: https://github.com/timClicks/slate

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdf/info .Specially the part that says: "PDF files generally contain drawing instructions. There's no such thing as "a table" in most PDF files. There are lines, glyphs, and raster images (and clipping, and color spaces, and so forth). It is all but impossible to determine what is or isn't a table in an arbitrary PDF file."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download slate from  [github](https://github.com/timClicks/slate) and then do `import slate`. Also refer [slate tutorial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate)

```
>>> with open('example.pdf') as f:
...    doc = slate.PDF(f)
...
>>> doc
[..., ..., ...]
>>> doc[1]
'Text from page 2...'
```

Answer (score 1):

`Slate` does the job of extracting text from a PDF. You just make a `slate.PDF(open('file.pdf), 'r'))` object, assign it to a variable, and print it.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate

Comment: As you can see in the comment...   
Yes I tried to do that but python return "NameError: name 'slate' is not defined". Is there some import to do?

Comment: @pp94 Yes, you have to `import slate`, and you also have to install it in the CMD using `pip install slate`.